# Is there a cannonical way to do login in GRPC

Tags: java, grpc, grpc-java

As the title says is there a cannonical safe way to implement login in GRPC (I'm using Java). I'm currently sending the login and password over TLS, checking them at the server and sending back a Session ID that needs to be sent with each message but I was wondering if there is a better/simpler way to do this.

Comment: Authentication is baked in - https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/

Answer (score 0):

Yes/No, possibly... If your API is not public then you could consider using a basic ApiKey instead of a session id.

If it's public then you have bigger things to consider.

- With your current implementation, how long is the Session ID valid for?
- What happens when the Session ID expires?
- How do you refresh the Session ID?
- How do you revoke the Session ID?

Take a look at the documentation here: https://grpc.io/docs/guides/auth/ for some ideas.

I'd also recommend reading up on oAuth2.